# Trying to install kallisto in Docker container

Tags: apt, package-management, docker

I am trying to download [Kallisto](https://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/download) in a Docker container. When I run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install kallisto
```

interactively in the container, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kallisto
```

That being said, I have `kallisto` installed on my machine outside the container. When I do `sudo apt-get install kallisto` outside the container, I can successfully install it. Thus, I looked what package repo it can be found in by running `apt-cache policy kallisto`:

```
kallisto:
  Installed: 0.46.1+dfsg-2build1
  Candidate: 0.46.1+dfsg-2build1
  Version table:
 *** 0.46.1+dfsg-2build1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So in the container, I tried:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
apt-add-repository http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
apt-get update
apt-get install kallisto
```

but I still get the same error. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: @N0rbert no I still get the same issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

To create Docker container with `kallisto` we need to create a Dockerfile with the following contents:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y kallisto
CMD which kallisto
```

then build it by

```
docker build . -t focal-kallisto
```

and run

```
docker run -it focal-kallisto
```

as the result it will show `/usr/bin/kallisto`, so it is actually installed inside the container.